# Which middleware I should use for HomeController since I'm using Passport

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using **Laravel / VueJS**, I'm using Passport for Authentication.

I have three pages: **Login, Register, HomeController**

My Question is since now I'm using Passport to login ( Token ), which middleware I should use for HomeController? I tried to use:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

but it didn't work since I'm sending the Bearer token using Postman just for test.

HomeController contains a static view with no dynamic data, but I want to protect it, so that only logged users can see it.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "but didn't worked since I'm sending the Bearer token using Postman just for test"... Try sending the request without the token to test if it is protected

Comment: just try the home controller request without the token, and also if it protected then it will show you unauthorized error message. you can also try the custom middleware to just check the bearer token there in the middleware and authorize the request accordingly

Answer (score 0):

in your application's config/auth.php configuration file the driver should be set to passport :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#installation

as for the middleware, it stays the same : `auth:api`